# AngularJS Show Button on Model Change

Tags: angularjs

i got a Model in a ng-repeat :

```
<tr ng-repeat="expert in experts">
                <td>{{expert.expertName}}</td>
                <td ng-mouseleave="editMode = false">
                    <span ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode = !editMode">{{expert.mail}}</span>
                    <input class="width100" type="text" ng-show="editMode" value="{{expert.mail}}" />
                </td>
                <td><input class="width100" type="checkbox" ng-model="expert.locked" ng-click="showSaveButton = ! showSaveButton"/></td>
                <td class="width100">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" ng-show="showSaveButton" value="SAVE" ng-click="confirmSave(expert)" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn-warning btn-primary btn" value="GENERATE" ng-click="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

When i Update a Model (eG expert.locked or Mail changed) i want to show the save Button for this model. I googled and found nothing.

Can anyone help me ?

EDIT : The Save Button `<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" ng-show="showSaveButton" value="SAVE" ng-click="confirmSave(expert)" />` has to be shown when the expert.mail or expert.locked changes

Comment: No one has an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the `ng-click="showSaveButton = ! showSaveButton"`

here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aLDJJ/1724/)

Comment: Ok but what i am doing in the Inpout Field for the Mail ? I want to track the Checkbox and the Input Field

Comment: what are the conditions in order to show the button ?

Comment: ShowSave button has to be shwon when the expert.mail or the expert.locked is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="expert in experts">
                <td>{{expert.expertName}}</td>
                <td ng-mouseleave="editMode = false">
                    <span ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode = !editMode">{{expert.mail}}</span>
                    <input class="width100" type="text" ng-show="editMode" value="{{expert.mail}}" />
                </td>
                <td><input class="width100" type="checkbox" ng-model="expert.locked"/></td>
                <td class="width100">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" ng-show="showSaveButton" value="SAVE" ng-click="confirmSave(expert)" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn-warning btn-primary btn" value="GENERATE" ng-click="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was to Easy : Just Use ng-change and then you can trigger a vairiable showButton or something

```
ng-change="showSaveButton = true"
```